# Generate a set of values that has a given correlation with n given other sets of values

Tags: statistics, correlation

Given lists $L_1, \dots, L_n$ of, let's say, 2000 values each and arbitrary numbers $c_1, \dots, c_n$, is it possible to generate a random list of 2000 values that has correlation $c_i$ with $L_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: In other words, you want to create new lists having the same distributions and correlations than L1,...,Ln but with different values, is it correct? Why not just add some noise + a threshold?

Comment: No, I want a single list that has correlation c1 with L1, ... ,cn with Ln. Correlations that L1,...,Ln have between each other are irrelevant. Maybe I added unnecessary confusion with that second paragraph, so I'll remove it.

Comment: It would be very helpful to add a small table with some values to see exactly what is expected.

Comment: OK, let's say I simply have two lists L1 = [1,2,3] and L2 = [4,5,6]. Let's say we are given two numbers 0.4 and 0.6 that are unrelated to L1 and L2. Is it possible to randomly generate another list L3 such that corr(L1,L3) = 0.4 and corr(L2, L3) = 0.6? In the case where such a list can exist, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to take the correlation values from each list and apply a random rule to have the expected result.

Here is an example with 3 Lists:

```
import random
import numpy as np

# List of lists of n values

L1 = [10, 12, 32, 23, 12, 25, 10, 6, 8]
L2 = [5, 8, 15, 52, 56, 3, 2, 31, 45]
L3 = [21, 18, 6, 9, 26, 15, 9, 16, 26]

n = len(L1)

# Correlation values
c1 = 0.9
c2 = 0.2
c3 = 0.1

L = []


for i in range(0, n):
    
    noise1 = np.random.random()-0.5
    noise2 = np.random.random()-0.5
    noise3 = np.random.random()-0.5
    
    new_value = ((L1[i]+noise1)*c1 + (L2[i]+noise2)*c2 + (L3[i]+noise3)*c3)/(c1+c2+c3)
    L.append(new_value)

# Correlations between L and original lists
corr1 = np.corrcoef(L, L1)[0][1]
corr2 = np.corrcoef(L, L2)[0][1]
corr3 = np.corrcoef(L, L3)[0][1]

print(corr1, corr2,corr3)
print(L)
```

Note: you can limit the random choice to the closest values around i, if you want to keep a similar order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tried running your code multiple times and corr1, corr2 are never close to c1, c2.

Comment: It depends how differerent the lists are. If you have 2 very different lists with a high coefficient (ex: 0.8), the resulting list will not have their coefficient at all. I've modified the code to have a more realistic result. I've also added some noise.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know to provide additional information.

Comment: I don't think it answers my question, sorry. Your code outputs 0.84, 0.44, -0.33 whereas you defined c1, c2, c3 to be 0.9, 0.2, 0.1.

Comment: It is because the algorithm has done "its best" to reach this result. Imagine that you have 2 very different curves, and you want a 3rd one to have a correlation of them at 0.9. This is impossible because there is no curve that could correlate that high with 2 very different curves. At best, you may have 0.4 and 0.6, and if one curve has more deviations, you may have 0.7 and 0.3. It depends on many factors, but using the proposed solution would at least try to be closer to the coef objectives.

Comment: I also tried with an example of L1, L2, L3, c1, c2, c3 such that I knew in advance that a good L exists for these exact inputs, and it still gave me outputs that were much too far from c1, c2, c3.

Comment: It is around 0.8,03,-03 for me, which is not very far.

Comment: Do you think that your objective is mathematically feasible or even possible? I don't think so (I've given some arguments), and I would be happy to be wrong. If you have a better solution, please let me know.